# Enable Local Disk Encryption with EMR

Tags: hdfs, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

As per [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-data-encryption-options.html) on how to enable at rest Encryption for local disks in EMR, there are 2 methods specified. I am interested in using the Open Source HDFS encryption.

```
Data encryption on HDFS block data transfer is set to true and is 
configured to use AES 256 encryption.
```

How is this set up?

If this is some setting in the hdfs-site.xml, how do I set this as part of my cloudformation template when deploying the EMR cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define a security configuration that enables local disk encryption for the above to be used.

No need to meddle with hdfs-site.xml directly.

Documentation for creating a security configuration can be found at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-create-security-configuration.html